# Missing "References" heading

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, elsarticle

The word "References" does not appear before the references which I entered in my paper. The packages I am using are:

```
\documentclass[final,times,1p,leqno,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
```

What is the reason of this issue?

Comment: Has been asked (and answered) on comp.text.tex on november 2009, the title of the question is "Problem with references - elsarticle"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `elsarticle` class will remove the bibliography heading by declaring

```
\let\bibsection\relax
```

if the `amsrefs` package is not loaded. You can override the class behaviour by adding, e,g.,

```
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
```

to your document preamble.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While the version on CTAN has this issue, the current version downloaded from the Elsevier website does not (the `\let\bibsection\relax` line is commented out).