# I don't see reference title in my paper!

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing “References” heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56105/missing-references-heading)

If you compile the code below you will see my problem.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My Paper's Title}

\author{Mohammad}

\address{Department of Electrical Engineering}

\begin{abstract}
If you compile this code, you will see the problems!
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Please help me.
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}\label{introduction}
A test section.

\section{Proposed Method}\label{introduction}
As you see there is no (3. Reference)

\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{pose}


\end{document}
```

thanks.

Comment: I solve the blank page problem.

Comment: Glad you solved the first problem. With regard to the present question, I just remembered http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56105/missing-references-heading. Please check if my answer there solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really help me. you really helped me to complete the paper in a proper time. thanks a lot. Bye.